# отправка формы на почту c помощью ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, email, form

Есть код для стандартной отправки формы, не пугайтесь, тут 3 формы одинакового вида. Создал бесплатный хостинг и кинул проверочную форму, но она не пришла на мой mail, прописанный в PHP. Подскажите почему?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
    <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Заголовок формы">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="name form-control" placeholder="Представьтесь, пожалуйста">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-mail" class="col-form-label">Ваш email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="recipient-mail" class="email form-control" placeholder="example@mail.ru">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-phone" class="col-form-label">Ваш телефон:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="recipient-phone" class="phone form-control" placeholder="+7">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Сообщение:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message-text" class="message form-control" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Заказать</button>
</form>

<form id="form2" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
    <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Заголовок формы">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="name form-control" placeholder="Представьтесь, пожалуйста">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-mail" class="col-form-label">Ваш email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="recipient-mail" class="email form-control" placeholder="example@mail.ru">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-phone" class="col-form-label">Ваш телефон:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="recipient-phone" class="phone form-control" placeholder="+7">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Сообщение:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message-text" class="message form-control" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Заказать</button>
</form>

<form id="form3" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
    <input type="hidden" name="formData" value="Заголовок формы">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="name form-control" placeholder="Представьтесь, пожалуйста">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-mail" class="col-form-label">Ваш email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="recipient-mail" class="email form-control" placeholder="example@mail.ru">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-phone" class="col-form-label">Ваш телефон:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="recipient-phone" class="phone form-control" placeholder="+7">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Сообщение:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message-text" class="message form-control" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Заказать</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            var formID = $(this).attr('id'); // Получение ID формы
            var formNm = $('#' + formID);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'form.php', // Обработчик формы отправки
                data: formNm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    // Вывод текста результата отправки в текущей форме
                    $(formNm).html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Код PHP:

```
    <?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['formData'])) {$formData = $_POST['formData'];}
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {$message = $_POST['message'];}
    $to = "sayapov.ainur@mail.ru"; /*Укажите ваш адрес электронной почты*/
    $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = utf-8";
    $subject = "$formData";
    $message = "$formData\n\nОткуда: $email \n\nОтправитель: $name \n\nТелефон: $phone \n\nСообщение: $message";
    $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($send == 'true')
    {
    echo "<center>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения! Наши специалисты свяжутся с вами в течение часа.</center>";
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "<center><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено! Проверьте правильность введенных данных</b></center>";
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "Попробуйте еще раз";
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. Почтовый сервер на этом хостинге настроен? (Или существует ли вообще?)
2. Логи смотрели?

Comment: `eho` какое было?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar: Спасибо, логов на хостинге почтовых нет, проверил почтовый сервер, не подключен DMARC, он же не должен мешать отправке?

Comment: @doox911: echo:Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, я не подключил SMTP.